# PHP while() function is running my query 3 times

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My problem is that:
I have a users table in MySQL. I made a query with MySQLi which looks like:

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT condition,name,money FROM users WHERE fbid = ?")){

 $stmt->bind_param('s',$_SESSION['FBID']);

 $stmt->execute();

 $stmt->store_result();

 $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

 $stmt->bind_result($condition,$name,$money);

 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
```

And here's my problem, because I want different users to add equal usernames to their ids. So, my code is the following:

```
if($_GET['name']!='' && $money>'500'){
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET `condition` = `condition` + 5, `money` = `money` - 5 WHERE fbid = ? AND name = ?");
 $stmt2->bind_param("ss", $_SESSION['FBID'],$_GET['name']);
 $stmt2->execute();
 $stmt2->close();
```

I want to update only that value in the database where user ID = `$_SESSION[fbid]` and name = `$_GET[name]`. So if I have an account with id `1922838445` and I have three names, for example, `John`, `Joe`, and Jill and `$_GET[name]=='Joe'` then update only that value at the same ids. It works until that point that update only the got value, but it does that 3 times... Because of `while ()` maybe??? How can I fix it?

The two code samples have to come one after!! Because of checking the value of money..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for the first `SELECT` and the loop, just put the condition on `money` into the `UPDATE` query itself.

```
if ($_GET['name'] != '') {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
        UPDATE users 
        SET condition = condition + 5, money = money - 5
        WHERE fbid = ? AND name = ?
        AND money > 500")
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_SESSION['FBID'], $_GET['name']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead to get only one record:

It gets only the record you need because it has a WHERE clause on both parameters that you plan to update, instead of only a partial match on the fbid like you had before.

Before you were getting 3 records because you had a partial key search, then looping through the records and updating the same record over and over against, regardless of the value of the second part of the key in the record you were looping against.

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT condition,name,money FROM users WHERE fbid = ? AND name = ?")){

 $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_SESSION['FBID'],$_GET['name']);

 $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be good for you to _explain_ your answer. Why does this work the way it does? How does it solve the problem? Why is OPs code not working as expected?

Comment: is that better?

Comment: Much :) I assume with this update you are also much more likely to get upvotes and as such more rep. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Mysqli doesn't have named parameters. You're confusing it with PDO.

Comment: Along with what @Barmar said, I believe you are also using `bind_param()` incorrectly. (I haven't used MySQLi in a while)

Comment: Yeah, it's does not worked very well.. But I have one more problems: I want to print out every name to the site and then, by clicking on a link MYWEBSIE.com/abc.php?name=Joe then have to update... Because the details are should be written out.. all the three or twenty..

Comment: @krisz44g This is another question. According to the rules of this community please accept the answer, that was the most helping for you (if it solved your problem) and ask a new question for that problem, even if they are related.

Comment: Okay, I accepted the most useful, but I'm a little unhappy, because I wrote one of the table details wrong in my question :'( I programmed for 24 hours so I'm a little tired :S

Comment: The update connects to an other table, not to that where from the money detail comes